# sorting by first name dont work

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code that returns the nth largest salary

```
SELECT first_name,Last_name,salary
FROM Employees E1 
WHERE (N-1) = (
                SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(E2.Salary)) 
                FROM Employees E2 
                WHERE E2.Salary > E1.Salary
               );
```

and it returns multiple records if they have the same salary.
however, when I try to order by first_name it still returns a result that is not ordered alphabetically.

sample output

```
Nancy   Greenberg   12000.00
Alberto Errazuriz   12000.00
```

desired output

```
    Alberto Errazuriz   12000.00
    Nancy   Greenberg   12000.00
```

I used order by first_name ASC;

Comment: Add some sample table data, the current result, and the wanted result - all as formatted text, not images. Also show us your ORDER BY.

Comment: Where are you ordering?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is simpler to move the `-1` to the subquery.  Adding the `ORDER BY` to the *outer* query should order the result set:

```
SELECT first_name, Last_name, salary
FROM Employees E1 
WHERE <N> = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT E2.Salary) + 1
             FROM Employees E2 
             WHERE E2.Salary > E1.Salary
            )
ORDER BY first_name;
```

If this does not work, please edit your question and provide sample data.